# socket_bind() [function.socket-bind]: unable to bind address [13]: Permission denied

Tags: php, sockets, binding, port, phpwebsocket

I am building a chat application based on websocket protocol.I am uploading this on an apache server and i am getting this error :

"Warning: socket_bind() [function.socket-bind]: unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use"

I am using port no. 12346. When i checked this port's status i got "12346 is not responding".

I have checked many ports on my remote server ,none of them is responding.So please tell me how to check if there is a usable port which i can use??

I have also used port 80 and 443 but i am getting the error:

```
Permission Denied
```

Comment: You can't open ports bellow a certain number without root privilege. This definitely includes standard service ports such as 80 and 443. Also, if your calling the script via a web server it might not let you listen on *any* ports

Answer (score 1):

I see that that you're using apache - this is most likely the problem. You need to run the script as a deamon or at least from a shell, and you will need root privileges for ports under 1024 unless you're on a windows host.